# Getting extrinsic data with the transaction hash

Tags: extrinsic, rpc

I've successfully submitted the extrinsic RPC call and got a JSON response

```json
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "result": "0x715b0b0d105920a928ad005bd525a68d6b8b60e73afa043174fe0db2f7133db8",
    "id": 1
}
```

Knowing the transaction hash, how can I know whether the extrinsic got accepted or rejected by the network. Is there a way to see the error code in case of rejection? Thanks

### Update

I'm calling a method in a custom pallet. The runtime logic returns a `System.ExtrinsicFailed` exception with a specific error.

[image]

But the submitted extrinsic is still included to the block.

```json
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "result": {
        "block": {
            "extrinsics": [
                "0x280402000b74c3add97f01",
                "0xe9018400d43593c715fdd31c61141abd04a99fd6822c8558854ccde39a5684e7a56da27d010a53e10e6c6b4e3f0ec5faf3e4db39e1b70766873ae3462e53c90b1316565e408c7c74dc6bdf4d4274871d44ec27956fd6547b733e6cfacf9b34526251c1ad84006400080040e00b2d48eee975515138552126e2bf8600"
            ],
            "header": {
                "digest": {
                    "logs": [
                        "0x06617572612041ab601000000000",
                        "0x0561757261010126d20fb044834f6f1a9d036403af6ad87bfec598889ddcc174fbaf190c75ce77120ae859cc739b1089850346409868ef229989a91ee08b5d860ed838bc79d68f"
                    ]
                },
                "extrinsicsRoot": "0x35f1510c6c4704691c742a107d2a53e722b65e08d268a369052f728d35b981a1",
                "number": "0x19b4",
                "parentHash": "0x6f589b4e8d8885f59b726689d702e86f55af07af281e4c9377987841c31e7dd4",
                "stateRoot": "0xa9e3f1fc62e82c501289266655eabeb04c3488d67184d683ed27bd4a3e336350"
            }
        },
        "justifications": null
    },
    "id": 1
}
```

What are logs? Do I understand correctly, that they also can be deserialised? Do they correspond to extrinsic with the same index?
Thanks

Answer (score 6):

I'm facing the same kind of question I think. The problem is that it doesn't really matter if your extrinsic is executed correctly or not, if the transaction submitted is correct (the structure and data), it will be added to the chain.

I haven't find an easier way to determine if the execution was okay or not, but there's this page that I'm sure will help

Polkadot API: https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/cookbook/blocks#how-do-i-determine-if-an-extrinsic-succeededfailed

Keep in mind that the extrinsic hash might not be unique at some point, so you need to combine block number and extrinsic hash to ensure you are getting the right events.

The following threads are also useful:

*How to get extrinsic details by extrinsic hash*: https://github.com/polkadot-js/api/issues/2326

*Extrinsic hash from Event, How to?*: https://github.com/polkadot-js/api/issues/4240

Answer (score 5):

The Substrate `author_` RPC namespace has 2 submission mechanisms -

- `author_submitExtrinsic` - this only returns the hash, doesn't guarantee inclusion
- `author_submitAndWatchExtrinsic` - this is a subscription that returns the status of the extrinsic, e.g. Broadcast, InBlock, Finalized, etc.

Once the subscription reaches `InBlock(blockHash)` or `Finalized(blockHash)` you can get the DispatchResult from the block to determine the actual runtime execution status.

It may be rejected in the transaction pool already, e.g. a `Stale` status is an example of this, in that case it won't make it into a block, so it won't get to a `Finalized` state at all.

If you cannot submit & watch, a more limiting approach would be to watch `author_pendingExtrinsics` to see if it is unprocessed and check incoming blocks for inclusion. In this case you lose out on any won't-be-included statuses from the transaction pool.

Comment: Thank you, @Jaco. Yeah, the `author_submitAndWatchExtrinsic` method is  available only with web sockets. Unfortunately, I can't use it right now. Using RPC I get the `Subscriptions are not available on this transport` response.  I've updated the question and added more details.

Comment: The error shown above is from the system events. You need to read the events for the block where it is includes and check ExtrinsicSuccess/Failure to extract the errors for the extrinsic.