# Function to see whether transaction is finalized

Tags: polkadot-js, transactions

I am currently trying to use the javascript api to send dot between accounts and I was wondering if there was a function/way to find out whether a transaction is finalized just based off the transaction hash. I read the docs here: https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/start/api.tx.subs, I understand how to use the callback for status updates however I would really like a standalone function that takes in a transaction hash and outputs whether it is finalized if such a thing exists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Substrate the [transaction hashes are not unique](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/build-protocol-info#unique-identifiers-for-extrinsics) and there is no RPC that actually provides an index of this non-unique identifier. There are a couple of existing questions answered on this, see [this](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/2760/get-transaction-by-hash), [this](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/1393/getting-extrinsic-data-with-the-transaction-hash) and [this](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/626/to-get-the-extrinsic-data-from-the-extrinsic-hash).

If you wish to see if something is finalized, one approach would be to

- subscribe to the [finalized headers](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/rpc#subscribefinalizedheads-header),
- [retrieve the
  block](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/rpc#getblockhash-blockhash-signedblock)
  and
- check for the extrinsic you are after in the block